# X509 Certificate verification with Windows Crypto API

Tags: c, x509certificate, cryptoapi

I need to write a C program for Windows that receives a certificate from network (in PEM format) and validates its signature with a certificate chain file (which is already presented in the application's folder).

Writing such an application is pretty easy and strait forward with openssl library but seems a little complicated with the Windows Crypto API.

Here is what I've tried so far:

First I thought I can create a HCERTSTORE using the certificate-chain file:

```
HCERTSTORE hFileStoreHandle = CertOpenStore( 
CERT_STORE_PROV_FILENAME,
PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING, NULL,
(CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG | CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG),
L"certificate-chain.pem.cert");
```

Then I figured I can iterate through the store and get PCCERT_CONTEXT struct of certificates:

```
PCCERT_CONTEXT CAfileContext = NULL;
while(CAfileContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(
 hCertStore,
 CAfileContext)) {

    //start verification here
}
```

I don't know if I am on the right track or not but I'm facing two major problems here.

First is I don't know how to get the received certificate from buffer and convert it to a proper struct in order to validate its signature with certificate-chain file.

Second is I don't know how to verify a certificate signature using the CA chain file.

I'll appreciate all the suggestions and helps.

Comment: Don't write your own crypto code.

Comment: Agree with @stark, consider to use built-in `CertCreateCertificateChainEngine` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376032(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Actually I'm not intended to write my own, the problem is, I don't know how to do it using Crypt api.

Comment: Thanks @Crypt32, I've started to investigate how to use CertCreateCertificateChainEngine for my particular purpose.

Comment: @Crypt32, unfortunatly after couple of days digging into CertCreateCertificateChainEngine could not find the proper solution with this function.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sample code for you, hopefully it can help you.

```
HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
DWORD dwError = 0;
PCCERT_CONTEXT  pCert = NULL;

HCERTSTORE hCertStore = CertOpenStore(
    CERT_STORE_PROV_FILENAME,                   
    PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING,
    NULL,                                   
    (CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG | CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG),             
    L"certificate-chain.pem.cert");

do
{
    if ((pCert = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hCertStore, pCert)) == NULL)
        break;

    PCCERT_CONTEXT pcIssuer = NULL;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pcSubject = CertDuplicateCertificateContext(pCert);
    for (; NULL != pcSubject;)
    {
        DWORD dwFlags = 0;
        BOOL bret = TRUE;
        hr = S_OK;

        pcIssuer = CertGetIssuerCertificateFromStore(
            hCertStore, pcSubject, NULL, &dwFlags);

        if (pcIssuer == NULL)
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
            if (CRYPT_E_SELF_SIGNED != dwError)
            {
                hr = E_FAIL;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((bret = CertCompareCertificateName(
                    X509_ASN_ENCODING, 
                    &pcSubject->pCertInfo->Subject, 
                    &pcSubject->pCertInfo->Issuer)) == FALSE)
                {
                    hr = E_FAIL;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        HCRYPTPROV hprov = NULL;
        bret = CryptAcquireContext(
                    &hprov, nullptr, nullptr, PROV_RSA_FULL, 
                    CRYPT_SILENT | CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | CRYPT_NEWKEYSET);

        if (FALSE == bret)
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
            if (NTE_EXISTS == dwError)
                bret = CryptAcquireContext(
                        &hprov, nullptr, nullptr, PROV_RSA_FULL,
                        CRYPT_SILENT | CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
            if (FALSE == bret)
            {
                hr = E_FAIL;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ((bret = CryptVerifyCertificateSignatureEx(
            hprov, X509_ASN_ENCODING,
            CRYPT_VERIFY_CERT_SIGN_SUBJECT_CERT,
            (void*)pcSubject,
            CRYPT_VERIFY_CERT_SIGN_SUBJECT_CERT, 
            (void*)(pcIssuer == nullptr ? pcSubject : pcIssuer),
            0, nullptr)) == FALSE)
        {
            hr = E_FAIL;
            break;
        }

        if (nullptr == pcIssuer)
        {
            CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO msCert;
            msCert.Algorithm = 
                pcSubject->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.Algorithm;
            msCert.PublicKey.cbData = 
                sizeof(PETRUSTED_ROOTCERT_PUBKEY);
            msCert.PublicKey.pbData = 
                const_cast<LPBYTE>(PETRUSTED_ROOTCERT_PUBKEY);
            msCert.PublicKey.cUnusedBits = 
                pcSubject->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cUnusedBits;

            if (FALSE == CertComparePublicKeyInfo(
                X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 
                &pcSubject->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo, &msCert))
            {
                hr = E_FAIL;
                break;
            }
        }

        bret = CryptReleaseContext(hprov, 0);
        hprov = NULL;

        CertFreeCertificateContext(pcSubject);
        pcSubject = pcIssuer;
        pcIssuer = NULL;
    }

    if (pcIssuer != NULL)
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pcIssuer);

    if (pcSubject != NULL)
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pcSubject);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pCert);
        break;
    }

} while (pCert != NULL);

CertCloseStore(hCertStore, 0);

if (FAILED(hr))
    wprintf(L"Failed to verify X509 certification.\n");
else
    wprintf(L"Successfully verify X509 certification.\n");
```

Comment: Thank you @ravin.wang for sharing your solution. Actually I gave up native code and decided to use openssl when I was working on that project. Right now I can't test your code on that project but hopefully someone would find this code and let us know if its useful for this particular need.

Comment: I have written a runnable sample for windows OPM management, there are workable codes in https://github.com/wangf1978/D3DTest, the related implementation and sample code lie at CryptoUtil.cpp and OPMSessioncpp